# Return false if HTML Tags exist only at the beginning of a string

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, tags

I want to return false if html tags only exist at the beginning of a string. Else, if they exist inside a string, return true. What I'm able to do thus far, is return false if an html tag is in the beginning but if it's inside a string, everything from after the html tag gets deleted. And if the length of the text before the tag is true, then only the text before the html tag is kept, else it returns false

Examples:

- `Tha</bo` should return `Tha bo`, only strip off the Tag not everything after the tag
- `</Thabo` should return a modal with a message for invalid info

```js
function invalidInfo() {

 var returnVal = true;

 var valProjCode = window.document.getElementById("txtProjCode").value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
 
 valDestination = window.document.getElementById("txtDestination").value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

 if (valDestination.trim().length < 2 || valProjCode.trim().replace(/ /g, '').length < 5) {

     returnVal = false;
  try {
      $("#InvalidInfoModal").modal();
      $('#InvalidCusInfoModal').modal('hide')
      $('#MissingDateModal').modal('hide')
      $('#InvalidDateModal').modal('hide')
      $('#InvalidChars').modal('hide')
  }
  catch(err) {
   alert(err.message);
  }
 }

 return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Please add some example strings and what the outcome should be.

Comment: With Tag Inside: Tha</bo  == Tha  and With Tag at the Beginning </Thabo == Will return a modal with a message for invalid info

Comment: I have added the examples to your question. In the future, always give examples for the different outcomes and write them **directly** into the question text.

Comment: Also: your tag examples are for closing tags, I guess opening tags like `Tha</bo` should be treated the same?

Comment: If there's an HTML tag inside a string, only that Tag should be stripped off and maybe be replaced with a space, Only the Tag, rather than everything after the tag, which is what is happening right now. So Tha</bo should return Thabo/Tha bo instead of Tha. See the edit. And thanks for the Tip

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regular expression** to determine whether a string started with specific pattern. Try javascript regex `test()` method. You can find reference from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

The regular expression for matching string that start with html tag is `/^<([^>]+)>/ig`

Example:

```
var regex = /^<([^>]+)>/ig;
regex.test("abc<html>"); //return false
regex.test("<html>abc"); //return true
regex.test("abcd"); //return false
```